# Handle Zero value in Sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have created a test table which has a boolean field called "Inactive".
In *SqlServer* Inactive fields value can be either zero `0` or one `1`. But whenever I sqoop data from *SqlServer* to *Hive*, zero `0` get replaced with `NULL` in Hive.

But I need to keep `0` as is, then how can I Handle zero value in sqoop?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
     IndividualUid string,
     First string,
     Middle string,
     Last string,
     Inactive boolean
)row format delimited fields terminated by ',' location 'Individual';
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please be clear on the question. Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Formatted and fixed grammar

Comment: can you run a query `select cast(Inactive as boolean) from test` and show the results?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly going wrong in your case. can you try below.

```
mysql> create table tablewithboolean (id int, name varchar(10), status boolean);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc tablewithboolean;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into tablewithboolean values(1, 'One', false);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into tablewithboolean values(1, 'Two', true);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from tablewithboolean;
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | status |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | One  |      0 |
|    1 | Two  |      1 |
+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Create external table in HIVE**

```
hive> use hadoopexam;

create external table hivetablewithboolean (id int, name varchar(10), status boolean)
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' 
location '/user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean';

hive> create external table hivetablewithboolean (id int, name varchar(10), status boolean)
    > row format delimited fields terminated by ',' 
    > location '/user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean';


hive> describe hivetablewithboolean;
OK
id                      int                                         
name                    varchar(10)                                 
status                  boolean                                     
Time taken: 0.266 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

**import the data from mysql to hive.**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/retail_db --username retail_dba --password cloudera \
--query 'select id, name, status from tablewithboolean where $CONDITIONS' \
--hive-table hadoopexam.hivetablewithboolean \
--target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean \
--split-by id
```

**Check the target directory.**

```
[root@quickstart spark]# hadoop fs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean/
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup          0 2018-02-28 15:56 /user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup         23 2018-02-28 15:56 /user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean/part-m-00000
[root@quickstart spark]# hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/warehouse/hivetablewithboolean/part-m-00000
1,One,false
1,Two,true
```

**Check the content of Hive table**

```
hive> select * from hivetablewithboolean;
OK
1   One false
1   Two true
Time taken: 0.147 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s
```

Comment: I am also getting same result, instead of false and true I want 0 and 1 as it is..

Comment: @Ajinkya, I think you can change that. Hive stores the boolean data as true or false.  try this insert into hivetablewithboolean values(3, 'three', 1);
and see the data in hive table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like below in the import statement:

--query 'select id,name,cast(status as decimal) new from tablewithboolean  where $CONDITIONS' \